# Dynamic linq query not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I am using the Dynamic Linq library found here:

http://speakingin.net/2008/01/08/dynamic-linqparte-1-usando-la-libreria-de-linq-dynamic/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx

I have the following code in my DAL:

```
public IQueryable<RequestBase> GetRequestByCustomQuery(string strql)
            {
                return _context.RequestBases.Where(strql);
            }
```

And I have the following code in my page:

```
protected void BtnOpenReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var list = RequestBaseBL.GetRequestByCustomQuery("RequestNumber = 12");
            GrvResults.DataSource = list;
            GrvResults.DataBind();
        }
```

I am omitting all other layers, but there is a BL, then a Dal Facade and then the DL, but all they do is pass the string to the last layer, the DAL.

I get the exception

```
Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'
```

The object is like this:

```
public class RequestBase
    {
        public int RequestBaseId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
        public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsOnHold { get; set; }

        public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
        public virtual Requester Requester { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<WorkflowHistory> WorkflowHistories { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's maybe because your RequestNumber is defined as a string in the object. But in the request 
`"RequestNumber = 12"`
12 is considered as a number.

Try with `"RequestNumber == \"12\""`

You can't use simple quote either, because it's for character, that is to say only one letter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change

```
"RequestNumber = 12"
```

to

```
"RequestNumber = '12'"
```

Becuase `RequestNumber` is a `string`. If you do not have the `''` around it will think that it is an `int`

**Edit**

You can also try `"RequestNumber == \"12\""` with escape character

Comment: I did it like you said:   var list = RequestBaseBL.GetRequestByCustomQuery("RequestNumber = '12'");
           and then this error came Character literal must contain exactly one character

Answer (score 0):

I got it your "RequestNumber" is string and would have to use Equals("12"), try this it should definitely work.

RequestNumber.Equals("12")

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'

Comment: I tried this == with single quotes and I got this: Character literal must contain exactly one character